# Show that subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

Show that subset $\mathbb{R}^2$ , $(0,1]\times (0,1] \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is connected with the usual topology

I am not sure that the question is well formulated because I know that the sets $(0,1]$ and $\{(0,0)\}$ are connected then the product $(0,1]\times (0,1]$ is connected but the union of connected is connected if its intersection is not disjoint and in this case:

$$(0,1]\times (0,1] \cap \{(0,0)\}=\emptyset$$

Comment: The question is well-formulated.

Comment: how would you proceed for the proof?

Comment: Note for two connected sets that "not disjoint"="intersection not empty" implies "the union is connected", but "disjoint"="intersection empty" does not imply "the union is not connected". In $\mathbb{R}$, just think of $[0,1], (1,2]$.

Comment: The question is fine, you've just shown that you can't prove it with that particular theorem.

Comment: I understand, so I'll try it by contradiction.

Comment: Could consider $B=(0,1]\times (0,1]\cup {(0,0)}$, $A=(0,1]$ and $\overline{A}=[0,1]$ are connected  and as $A\subset B \subset \overline{A}$ then B is connected.  can this argument be used?

Comment: You wrote: _“the union of connected is connected if its intersection is not empty”_. Maybe you can use this fact to prove the required connectedness, but _with another choice_ of sets?

Comment: @MarcoRoys yes this argument can be used (assuming $A = (0,1] \times (0, 1]$ and $B = [0,1] \times [0,1]$)

Comment: @OsamaGhani No. Because your $B$ is not a subset of the set in the question!

Comment: @jpboucheron oof brain fart, I meant $A$ and $\overline{A}$, thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $B=(0,1]\times (0,1]\cup \{(0,0)\}$ and $A=(0,1]^2$

Note that $\overline{A}=[0,1]^2$ and A are connected and as $A\subset B\subset \overline{A}$  then B is connected.

Comment: Another solution was to consider you set as the union of two connected non-disjoint sets: $\mathopen]0,1]\times\mathopen]0,1]$ and $\{(x,x)\ \mid\ 0 \leqslant x\leqslant 1\}$.